# PHP SOAP Message creation from stdClass Object

Tags: php, oop, soap

So I have soap connection to some services. The App I'm creating is fully object oriented. The data for messages I'm sending are therefore in PHP in stdClass objects (it is extended by my Classes - representants of data in future xml document with predeclared public $variables). Everything is fine as long as I have to create documents like:

```
<Request>
<paramsList>
<someParam></someParam>
<someParam></someParam>
<someParam></someParam>
<someParam></someParam>
</paramsList>
<moreData></moreData>
</Request>
```

Now the problem is to create structure like:

```
<Request>
<paramsList>
<someParam id="3"></someParam>
<someParam id="4"></someParam>
<someParam id="18"></someParam>
<someParam id="512"></someParam>
</paramsList>
<moreData isImportant="false"></moreData>
</Request>
```

Is it possible (and if - how?) to add these things to stdObject so I don't have to change execution of SOAP functions from this simple form:

```
$client->functionToExecute($stdObjectOrientedData);
```

Example object and usage:

```
class Request extends \stdClass
{
    public $paramsList;
    public $moreData;
}

$objectToSend = new \stdObject();
$request = new Request();
$request->paramsList = $someParamsObjectsArray;
$request->moreData = $someData;
$objectToSend->Request = $request;

$client->functionToExecute($objectToSend);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone visit this question, here is the answer.

If WSDL file is created properly, PHP will generate response with using normal StdClass objects. just name properties as they are named in request.

If WSDL has errors, only thing you can do is to make requests manualy from templates.